# Mover pasta/arquivos entre repositórios sem perder Histórico de alterações

Tags: versionamento, branch, mercurial

> **Contexto:**
>   Tenho um ambiente de versionamento no **Mercurial** utilizando TortoiseHG para visualização e commits e arquivos. Quero mover uma **pasta de um repositório para outro e sem perder o histórico de alterações**, gostaria de saber se é possível e como.
>
> Para efeito de explicação, vamos supor que tenho os **repositórios A e B**, ambos sendo utilizado a anos, e com **centenas de alterações**.

**Objetivo:**
No repositório **A** tenho a pasta (e com cerca de 200 arquivos e vários formatos):

```
C:\Repositorios\A\projetos\projeto1\artefatos
```

Gostaria então de **mover** a pasta **artefatos** com o seu conteúdo, para o repositório **B**, da qual tem uma estrutura de pasta diferente:

```
C:\Repositorios\B\objetos\arquitetura\etc\etc\artefatos
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dois repositórios, o [Velho](https://bitbucket.org/zmarcos/velho91593) e o [Novo](https://bitbucket.org/zmarcos/novo91593).
São totalmente diferentes.

Precisamos adicionar o conteúdo do repositório velho para o repositório novo. Mas cada um tem o seu ramo `default`. O que podemos fazer para ajudar o Mercurial?

A solução parece simples: **Crie um ramo novo, no velho respositório (um que não existe no novo repositório), sincronize com o novo repositório, e mescle (`merge`) este ramo com o ramo `default`**. Confira abaixo, os passos a seguir:

1. Estado inicial dos repositórios [Velho](https://bitbucket.org/zmarcos/velho91593) e o [Novo](https://bitbucket.org/zmarcos/novo91593).
   [image: Estrutura do repositório velho]
   No Velho temos apenas o diretório `x1`
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
   No Novo temos a estrutura `a\b\c`
2. Mudar arquivos no repositório Velho, seguindo a mesma estrutura do repositório Novo. Excluir arquivos que não são desejados. Detectar as mudanças corretamente.
   [image: pop-up de mudanças]
   [image: seleção de mudanças]
3. Criar novo ramo no repositório Velho, aqui chamado de `velhodefault`.
   [image: criação de ramo]
   [image: confirmação de ramo]
   Depois de criado o novo ramo, fazer `commit` (com todas as alterações efetuadas no passo 2).
4. No repositório Velho, adicionar conexão para o repositório Novo. Pode ser um caminho local, usando protocolo `file://`.
   [image: adicionar nova conexão]
5. Para sincronizar, escolha o repositório (a caixa do lado do botão de envio), e aperte o botão de envio (ícone com dois cilindros amarelos, e uma seta verde direcionada para cima).
   [image: enviar conteúdo de repositório velho para o novo]
   Neste momento o Mercurial não aceitará enviar o conteúdo. Pois como foi citado anteriormente, são dois repositórios distintos. Teremos que forçar a sincronização.
   [image: erro na sincronização]
   Para forçar, deve-se apertar o botão `opções`, situado na seção `Sincronizar`. Escolher a opção `Força push ou pull` e apertar o botão `Gravar`.
   [image: adicionar --force]
   Observe que aparecerá a caixa `Opções Selecionadas: --force`
   [image: observar --force]
   Tente sincronizar novamente. Confira como o conteúdo ficou no repositório Novo.
   [image: ramo velho no repositório novo]
6. Neste momento só falta mesclar o conteúdo do repositório Velho, escolhendo o ramo certo.
   [image: escolher o ramo para mesclar]
   Aperte o botão `Avançar`.
   [image: primeira etapa de mesclar]
   Aperte o botão `Avançar`.
   [image: segunda etapa de mesclar]
   Aperte o botão `Consolidar Agora`.
   [image: terceira etapa de mesclar]
   A mesclagem está concluída.
   [image: quarta etapa de mesclar]
7. Se tudo ocorreu bem, o estado final do repositório será assim. Pode-se perceber que temos o ramo `default` ocorrendo duas vezes. Sendo que o ramo `velhodefault` é a ligação entre eles.
   [image: estado final do repositório]

Sinta-se a vontade para clonar os repositórios [Velho](https://bitbucket.org/zmarcos/velho91593) e o [Novo](https://bitbucket.org/zmarcos/novo91593), e fazer suas experiências.

Comment: Desculpe a demora @Marcos, porém logo no passo 2, removo o arquivo do repositorio Velhor (ctrl+x) e colo no repositorio novo, porem não aparece no "Detectar Renomeações", mesmo abaixando a similaridade. O que posso fazer? Ambos estão sobre mesma base: C: \velho - c: \novo

Comment: Eu costumo esquecer de apertar o botão "Pesquisar renomeações". Porque o slider não atualiza automaticamente.

Comment: Mesmo pressionando o botão não "acha" mudança @Marcos Zolnowski

Comment: Entendi, você está colocando no novo diretamente. Precisa ser no repositório velho, imitando como é no novo.

Comment: Porque nesta etapa, nós estamos alterando o repositório velho, só nas próximas etapas mandaremos o conteúdo do velho para o repositório novo.

Comment: Mesmo eu fazendo no velho não identifica, ele mostra que foi removido e está sendo adicionado outro, mesmo eu selecionando os 2, ou um ou outro, não aparece no "Pesquisar Renomeações". (estou com a ultima versão do TortoiseHg instalado)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32460/discussion-between-marcos-zolnowski-and-david).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a extensão [ConvertExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) para exportar apenas aquele arquivo a partir do primeiro repositório em um novo repositório temporário, em seguida, usar `hg pull -f` para importar o novo repositório para o repositório de destino. 
Crie um arquivo filemap para o ConvertExtension

```
touch myfilemap
```

Adicione a linha em seu conteúdo:

```
include caminho/para/arquivo
```

Em seguida, digite:

`hg convert caminho/para/arquivo/original caminho/para/arquivo/destino --filemap "myfilemap"`

para criar o repositório temporário. Depois, no repositório de destino, digite:

`hg pull -f caminho/para/temporario`

para dar pull nesse arquivo com seu histórico. Isto irá criar um novo HEAD. Use

`hg merge`

para *mergea-lo* com a HEAD do seu repositório de destino.

Comment: Desculpa a demora, então ao executar o comando `hg convert` ... passando o filemap conforme disse está dando esse retorno: **"n├ú
o ├® um arquivo de bundle do Mercurial"**, consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Criou o arquivo de filemap? Eu modifiquei um pouco a resposta pra ficar mais fácil de entender

Comment: Estou em um ambiente Windows, não entendi ao certo em qual local criar o `myfilemap`, então o que fiz foi: **1°** Criei um repositorio temporario, **2°** criei um arquivo myfilemap na raiz do temp, **3°** adicionei o include dentro,**4°** Então ao digitar o comando `convert` retorna a mensagem mencionada acima, isso em qualquer um dos 3 repositorios

Comment: @David Desculpe, acabei não vendo seu comentário à época. Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Ainda não @Marcos Regis, eu e um amigo estudamos a extensão junto com o passo a passo que deu, e não conseguimos

Comment: Realmente não levei em consideração que pudesse ser Windows e também expliquei como fazer para um unico arquivo e não um diretório. Talvez seja mais simples tentar fazer isso em algum Linux (tipo um Live CD), dar push e depois pull pelo Windows.

Comment: Vai ser um pouco moroso, mas vou tentar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Não uso Tortoise, mas uso GIT e VSTS e já passei por algo parecido.

Eu resolvi criando uma nova Branch do projeto em um caminho diferente, e essa nova Branch passou a ser a principal. Assim passamos a trabalhar com o novo caminho.

Depois de todos os `commit`'s feitos, excluímos a pasta original/antiga nas máquinas dos desenvolvedores, pois os versionamentos continuarem no servidor.

Comment: Também é possível fazer isso com Mercurial, porém se fizer dessa forma perdemos todo o Histórico de Commits, e isso que não queremos. Obrigado.

Comment: @David, não deveria perder, pois Branches carregam o histórico de commits. Pelo menos no VSTS ele cria ponteiros que mostram de onde vieram os fontes da nova Branch e em seguida os versionamentos.

Comment: Então @Thiago Lunardi, no Mercurial quando criamos uma nova branch e movemos os arquivos de lugar ele considera que estamos removendo esses arquivos e adicionando novos arquivos. Ao executar o commando 'thg log file' temos a listagem de alterações do arquivo e isso que não queremos perder, pois sabemos o que foi feito em cada commit por estar ligado a uma OS.